# Radio button in dialog not automically being selected

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

In my alert dialog, I'm trying to highlight a specific radio button based on the language that the device is set to but I'm unsure of what code to add in order to achieve this. The question is where the solution I believe must go. What needs to be done to resolve this issue?

> E.g. When my device language is set to English, I want the 'English' radio button to be selected.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AlertDialog languageDialog;
    Context context = this;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Locale.getDefault().equals(Locale.ENGLISH)) {
                    ?
                }

                final CharSequence[] items = {
                        getResources().getString(R.string.english),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.french),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.japanese)
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.language);

                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        i = item;
                    }
                });

                languageDialog = builder.create();
                languageDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in `setSingleChoiceItems` is where you set the selected item. So, let's find out the index of `items` that corresponds to the current language of the device.

```
int defaultLang = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage())) {
        defaultLang = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then, just set the items for the dialog with this index

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, defaultLang, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        i = item;
    }
});
```

Comment: The for loop should go after you initialize the `items` array, and before you call `setSingleChoiceItems`

Comment: OK. Whenever I change the language, the necessary radio button  item does not become selected when I click the layout button again.

Comment: Try changing `.equals` to `.equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: No problem! For anyone who is curious, while digging into the `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()` I found out that some languages like `français` have the lowercase `f` (presumably because that's the grammar rule for languages in French, whereas `English` has the capital `E`)